# Android application can't back to MainActivity after Home key being pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have met a problem here in my applicaion:

I use a TabActivty in my application.
Tab 1 is MainActivitGroup extends ActvityGroup, and there is a MainActivity in MainActivityGroup.
Tab 2...
Tab 3...
Assume that there is a button in MainActivity, I press it and another activity called TestActivity will be shown in the foreground. Then I press home key to go back to the desktop and open another application, Now I press home key again and open my application, TestActiity will be shown, but when I press [back] key, it won't go back to MainActivity, it go back to the Desktop.
What happened to it? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: post your manifest. You've probably got some `launchMode` set there that shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you. There is actually a 'launchode' there in my manifest file, but if I remove it, another problem will appear, that is, sevral instance of MainActivityGroup.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Post your manifest and explain how you end up with multiple instances of MainActivityGroup.